# How to add a class to the invoked Angular component itself?

Tags: css, angular, angular9, angular2-hostbinding

If my main/parent component has the following:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <app-inner></app-inner>
</div>
```

How might I add a class to the component being invoked inside?

The goal is that the *app-inner* component presents a class when rendered so that I might reference it in my CSS, such as:

```
<app-inner class="inner-comp">
```

However, neither this direct placement of the *class* attribute, nor `[className]`, nor `[ngClass]` seem to actually add it.

Comment: You might want to use the tag selector for your use case. `app-inner { width: 100px }`

Comment: Direct placement of `class` attribute should work on component tags. What style is not applying to your component? Can you share the properties of the CSS class `inner-comp`?

Comment: @mamichels Thanks, but I am aware of that option. The project's lint rules do not allow that though (`selector-type-no-unknown`).

Comment: @Shravan placing the class attribute directly (`<app-inner class="inner-comp">`) does not work. When rendered the class attribute is simply not there. It's not a matter of how many properties/rules I have in my CSS.

Comment: Setting the class directly in the child component tag appears to work. Take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qeymjp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: @ConnorsFan thanks, I can see that in that example the _childClass_ is indeed rendered when it's placed in the parent's HTML... I wonder why the behavior is different in my case (several components do not render any class attribute).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without modifying the main/parent component's HTML, you might just simply use [**HostBinding**](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding) in the *InnerComponent*:

```
import { OnInit, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

export class InnerComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('className') componentClass: string;

  constructor() {
    this.componentClass = 'inner-comp';
  }
}
```

The declared string variable *componentClass* references directly the *className*'s *hostPropertyName* ("DOM property that is bound to a data property").

This automatically **adds to all invocations of `<app-inner>` the *inner-comp* class** when the *InnerComponent* renders, which will then allow direct references in the parent component's CSS, such as:

```
.inner-comp { height: 100%; }
```